# How to create a drawing in a window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, system.drawing

I've decided to learn a bit of WPF and I've created an application with the Mahapps Metro library and it interacts with a SQLite database (Unrelated but a bit of background).

I'd like to draw an object, let's say a triangle, in a new window.

I've seen this - [Click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms747393(v=vs.100).aspx) - but the drawing of the shape needs to be visible to the user. So the user will see the line being drawn from point A to B to C to A. The image will "reload" after a few seconds i.e. Clearing the window/canvas and redrawing the triangle.

Are they any libraries out there that might make this easier or does WPF have something else I can use to achieve this?

Also, the redrawing of the triangle will be in a separate thread running a loop. Something tells me this isn't going to be very efficient. Is there a better way initiate a "redraw"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My "answer" are some helpful searches and a few results that might help you get to the next step of deciding on a design that works for you.

Yes, WPF does have facilities to help you achieve some animation in drawing lines.

I searched for "wpf animate line drawing" and some interesting links for your research are:

[How do you animate a line on a canvas in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469283/how-do-you-animate-a-line-on-a-canvas-in-c)

[generating animated line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393908/generating-animated-line)

[Drawing line "slowly" programmatically with wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199514/drawing-line-slowly-programmatically-with-wpf)

Hopefully this gets you going in a good direction.  Best of luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you, your links were most helpful. You also gave me the "correct" search terms I could use to get the information I need.